# Simple Trigonometric Equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I am asked to solve the trigonometric equation $2cos \theta = \sqrt 3$

I rearrange it to $cos\theta = \frac{\sqrt3}{2}$

Now, at this point I am not sure what to do? Can someone **describe** to me the steps required? What identities do I need to know or be familiar with?

Cheers.

Comment: Are you familiar with the unit circle?

Comment: I have been introduced to it before. So quite yes.

Comment: Alright, I will write a descriptive answer using the unit circle then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, there are some exact values of the sine and cosine you should always remember:

[image]

Using this table, we identify the *first* solution to be $\frac{\pi}{6}$.

Now, recall there are *two* solutions:

[image]

How do we find the second solution?

Using the unit circle, we ask ourselves the following: in which quadrant of the unit circle is the cosine (which is represented by the $x$-value) positive? (since $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ is positive).

Well, in the first quadrant (the value we already found) and in the fourth quadrant:

[image]

The angle in the fourth quadrant is found by: $2\pi-\frac{\pi}{6}=\frac{11\pi}{6}$.

Using periodicity, we find the general answers to be:

$x_1=\frac{\pi}{6}+k\cdot2\pi \\ x_2=\frac{11\pi}{6}+k\cdot2\pi$

Comment: A truly comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the $\arccos$ (principal value) of both sides of the equation, yielding
$$\arccos\cos\theta=\theta^*=\arccos\frac{\sqrt3}2=\frac\pi6.$$
But this is not enough as there can be other values of $\theta$ that have the same cosine:

- the cosine function is periodic: $\cos\theta=\cos(\theta+2k\pi)$,
- the cosine function is even: $\cos\theta=\cos(-\theta)$.
  Put together, this gives
  $$\theta=\pm\theta^*+2k\pi.$$

[image]